# Spoofing grpc UnaryHandler for unit testing gRPC in Go

Tags: go, testing, grpc

I'm working on improving coverage for my Go gRPC server but I have run into trouble writing a test for the server's interceptor function because I'm unable to meaningfully satisfy the `UnaryHandler` type.

I have a function `Interceptor` with the following signature:

```
Interceptor func(
  ctx context.Context,
  req interface{},
  info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo,
  handler grpc.UnaryHandler, // <- my issue comes from here
) (interface{}, error)
```

I assumed that any gRPC method would satisfy the signature of `UnaryHandler`:

```
type UnaryHandler func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}) (interface{}, error)
```

So I tried passing in a method with this signature:

```
GetToken(ctx context.Context, req *AuthData) (*Token, error)
```

I imagined this would work, since this is what the Interceptor is actually doing (forwarding that RPC), but for some reason Go complains:

> cannot use authService.GetToken (type func(context.Context, *AuthData) (*Token, error)) as type grpc.UnaryHandler in argument to Interceptor

I went ahead and wrote a dummy function that correctly satisfies:

```
func genericHandler(ctx context.Context, req interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    return req, nil
}
```

which is fine since I don't particularly *need* to run any specific method when testing the interceptor. However I am curious as to why the actual method doesn't satisfy the constraints because (according to my understanding) it is being passed to the Interceptor function under hood whenever I call that RPC in the wild.

The most likely explanation is that the grpc UnaryHandler doesn't do what I'm thinking it does, but then what does it do?

Comment: Isn't it because it expects `interface{}` and you are passing and returning a reference? Maybe it would match `*interface{}`? That is, implementation-wise, it _should_ match a pointer, because an interface assumes a pointer, but I'm not sure about syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the function

```
GetToken(ctx context.Context, req *AuthData) (*Token, error)
```

is not of the same type as

```
type UnaryHandler func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}) (interface{}, error)
```

In `GetToken` the second parameter `req` is of type `*AuthData`, while in `UnaryHandler` `req` is of type `interface{}`. The returned `*Token` is not the same type as `interface{}`, neither.  This is the reason why you can't pass `GetToken` directly to the interceptor.

In your grpc services, you would write methods like

```
GetToken(ctx context.Context, req *AuthData) (*Token, error)
```

as handlers to do your server works. However, it's not an `UnaryHandler` as one may think.

Most of the transformation is done by the grpc/protobuf code generator. Base on your proto definition, it generates an interface, like this:

```
type XXXServer interface {
    GetToken(ctx context.Context, req *AuthData) (*Token, error)
}
```

You can see that it is this interface (not the UnaryHander) that your handler satisfies.

Under the hood, if you take a look on the `xxx.pb.go` file generated, you'll find some `_XXX_GetToken_Handler` that's actually doing the handler work. In this function, an (actual) `UnaryHandler` is defined, as:

```
func _XXX_GetToken_Handler(srv interface{}, ctx context.Context, dec func(interface{}) error, interceptor grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor) (interface{}, error) {
    // skip other preparations...
    // 
    handler := func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        return srv.(XXXServer).GetToken(ctx, req.(*AuthData))
    }
    return interceptor(ctx, in, info, handler)
}
```

Inside this `UnaryHandler`, it will cast your server to the `XXXServer` interface, and then invoke your handler (your code). And that shows how the `interceptor` is called.

Comment: I understand this and I appreciate your excellent explanation as to what's going on in the underlying implementation but there is still one point of confusion for me, shouldn't any value satisfy `interface{}`? Isn't `req *AuthData` identical to `req interface{}`? Since `interface{}` is used to satisfy unknown type constraints in go I assume that those functions are in fact the same type, so I'm wondering where the type error comes from

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak Go is statically typed. And interfaces in Go are still types. The static type of `req *AuthData` and `req interface{}` are not the same (one is *AuthData and the other is interface{}, obviously). Say you declare a variable `var req interface{}`, you can assign value of other types to this variable, as long as they satisfy this interface (in this special case, any type would satisfy). For example, you can write `x := 1; req = x`. But this fact doesn't make `req` and `x` the same static type.

Comment: Similarly, for the function `type UnaryHandler func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}) (interface{}, error)`, the fact that you can pass value of any type as the `req` argument to `UnaryHandler` doesn't make the static type interface{} identical to *AuthData. Thus we can know that the two function we have discussed are not the same static type, neither.